# jquery event - element added to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making chrome plugin. When page is loading, html has no element (for example with id "#var1"), this element will appear later on page.

Is it possible to set jquery checker?

My current solution:

```
$('body').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).attr("id") == "var1") {
    //My event here
  }
});
```

Is it possible to make my solution better and maybe like jquery code (event or function) with detecting classes and Ids by '.class' and '#id'?? (Current code detect only id)

Maybe something like:

```
$('body', '#var1').liveadding(function() {
  //My event here
});
```

Comment: Try coding a listener, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom and then the callback function as you showed in the second code block.

Comment: But need way to quick detecting which element was added to dom. And do event only if needed element was added. But I see only way for detecting DOM changing onDomChange() @jepser